# Failed to load resource: braintree js php integration aws ec2 lamp stack

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-ec2, payment, braintree

I am in need of some help with my JS PHP Braintree integration, using AWS EC2.

I have included the braintree PHP lib using require in my composer.json
    
   `{
  "require" : {
    "braintree/braintree_php" : "3.5.0"
      }
   }`

and I have installed it using
     `run php composer.phar install`

These are some sample files I was provided with from Braintree, I can use the script in my local computer on Dreamweaver. But when I upload the file to my instance, nothing shows.

When I check my google chrome log I get the error message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <?php
require_once '/home/ec2-user/vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree.php';
require_once '/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('test_marchant_id');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('test_public_key');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('test_private_key');

$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
?>

<head>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
<body>

<form id="checkout" method="post" action="server.php">
 <div id="dropin"></div>
  Amount:<input type="text" name="amount"><br>
  First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
  Email:<input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment">
    </form>

<script language='javascript'>
braintree.setup("<?php echo $clientToken; ?>", 'dropin', {
 container: 'dropin'
 });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check your error logs / turn on error reporting and find out why it's failing,

Comment: You've posted your sandbox API keys. You should edit your post to remove them and then regenerate the keys by going to the Braintree control panel and selecting Account > My User from the top right. On the My User page under Authorization click View API Keys. Finally, on the API Keys page click Generate New.

Comment: whoops, thanks! @Jessicad

Comment: Thanks @Epodax, in google console I get "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply removed the require autoload.php statement and the gateway is processing payments perfectly!